# R web-scraping on a multiple-level website with non dynamic URLs

Tags: r, web-scraping

I apologize in case I have not found a previous topic on this matter.
I want to scrape this website
http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/ 
In particular, this page includes a lot of links to country infos. Those links'structure is:

http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=KAZ

http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=AFG

and any of this page includes a News section I am interested in.
Of course, I could scrape page-by-page but that would be a waste of time.

I tried the following but that is not working:

```
countries <- read_html("http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/") %>%
  html_nodes(".linkcountry") %>%
  html_text()

country_news <- list()
sub <- html_session("http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/en/")

for(i in countries[1:100]){
  page <- sub %>% 
    follow_link(i)  %>% 
    read_html()
  country_news[[i]] <- page %>%
    html_nodes(".white-box") %>%
    html_text()
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "page-by-page" being a waste of time. Unless there's an API, you're going to have to do it page-by-page (perhaps you mean manually vs automatically?)

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean manually. Of course, I have to do it page-by-page.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all of the child pages from the top-level page:

```
stem = 'http://www.fao.org'

top_level = paste0(stem, '/countryprofiles/en/')

all_children = read_html(top_level) %>% 
  # ? and = are required to skip /iso3list/en/
  html_nodes(xpath = '//a[contains(@href, "?iso3=")]/@href') %>% 
  html_text %>% paste0(stem, .)

head(all_children)
# [1] "http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=AFG"
# [2] "http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=ALB"
# [3] "http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=DZA"
# [4] "http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=AND"
# [5] "http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=AGO"
# [6] "http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/index/en/?iso3=ATG"
```

If you are not comfortable with `xpath`, the CSS version would be:

```
html_nodes('a') %>% html_attr('href') %>% 
  grep("?iso3=", ., value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE) %>% paste0(stem, .)
```

Now you can loop over those pages & extract what you want

Comment: It is working, thanks.
I am trying to find a short loop to perform properly now.